# I need some help in this case of subordination

Tags: grammar

As I have studied and learnt from my teachers and from grammar books that we do not put comma before subordinating conjunction when subordinating clause comes after independent clause, but I have seen in a book by the name of "SAT 2 WRITING 4th edition" that they have used comma before ALTHOUGH and EVEN IF.

Comment: It helps to bear in mind that rules regarding comma are seldom set in stone.

Comment: Tushar Raj is right. Many people prefer using commas to indicate pauses in their speech. For ex: This,(pause) my friend,(pause) is a piece of art.

Answer (score 1):

A comma before *although* or *even if* in the middle of a sentence can create a nonessential clause. Note that a subordinate clause can't stand alone but a nonessential clause can (sometimes). So, the problem is you're seeing a comma before a subordinate conjunction, but what comes after it isn't actually a subordinate clause. This is perfectly grammatical.

> - The kid got bad grades in school, although he cheated on his tests.
> - The family will have a fun time on vacation, even if it isn't sunny.

If you were to remove everything after the comma, the remaining sentence is still complete, and if you were to remove everything before the comma (and the subordinate conjunction), you would still have a complete sentence.